# MySQL table structure suggestions?

Tags: mysql, database

Hey i'm currently working on a database project and simply can't think of a good way to save my data. The data being saved changes depending on what is being saved.

My current not-so-good table is:

```
User-ID | XLoc | YLoc | ZLoc | Data-ID | Data (String)
```

The data column is currently being saved as a string (serialized depending on object being saved) then unserialized. I understand serialization is a dumb idea when it comes to a proper database, but i haven't a clue on how else i could've done this.

I was thinking about assigning **"sub"** tables depending on the **Data-ID** then joining all the tables together on a search but i feel that wont be very efficient.

So my idea would play out like:

```
User-ID | XLoc | YLoc | ZLoc | Data-ID | Data-Index

Data-Index | SomeObjectRelatingData | SomeObjectRelatingData
```

Once again i just don't know how i'd put this all together so any help at all would be EXTREMELY helpful and i'm sorry if i was vague.

Example Data:

```
Particle-Name(string) | Material (int)
Time(long) | MeshType (int)
```

This data is currently serialized like so: Time:MeshType in string format. Once the data is retrieved from the database it's deserialized then changed back into it's formal type;

All the data needs to be accessed easily and they all share the User-ID, XLoc, YLoc, ZLoc.

Comment: Please describe the data you want to save.  Neither `Data (String)` nor `SomeObjectRelatingData` gives any clue at all on what facts you are trying to record.  An example of the serialized data would help, though we may need more information to identify functional dependencies in that data.

Comment: It looks like you have at least 3 types of elements - particles, materials and meshes, each located in 3D space and associated with a user.  What about time - what does it mean for a time value to be located in space?

Comment: Can multiple items exist at the same point in space?  Of the same type?  For the same user?

Comment: Yes, the User-ID can have millions of rows dedicated to them. But all this data needs to be accessed by either the User-ID, or the XLoc, YLoc, ZLoc. The data can be virtually anything - it's basically objects in C++/JAVA that need to store their primitive variables. So there is about 5 different data objects.